github action stage not triggering if previous stage failed
In our github actions workflow we want to rerun tests if the previous tests failed:
We made:
some-smoke-test-result:    
    name: Parse and analyze test results smoke test
    needs: [some-smoke-test]
    if: needs.some-smoke-test.outputs.some-id != ''
    runs-on: ${{inputs.runner-tag}}
    steps:
      - name: parse-test-result
        id: parse-test-result
        uses: some/some-actions/some-results@v1.5.0
        with:
          testarena-id: ${{ needs.some-smoke-test.outputs.some-id }}
  
some-smoke-test-rerun:
    name: Rerun some smoke test
    needs: [some-smoke-test, some-smoke-test-result]
    if: always() && needs.steps.some-smoke-test-result.outcome == 'failure' 

However the if statement at the step test-result-smoke-test is not working as expected,  when I only have the always() statement it is triggered as expected, but I only want to run it when the previous stage fails. For that reason I added && needs.steps.some-smoke-test-result.outcome == 'failure' However it is not triggering while the previous stage fails.
How should I trigger a stage ONLY if the previous stage failed
note i removed the earlier stages as everything else is working as expected.

There are some issues in your workflow configuration explaining why it's not working as expected.

The outcome variable is only available for steps (steps context) so you can't use it to check a job outcome status.
There is a result variable for jobs in the jobs context that can be used to validate the expected outcome status, using needs.<job_id>.result == 'failure'.


This workflow setup will work as you expect it to (adapting it to your context):
jobs:
  some-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Force job failure
        run: exit 1
  
  some-test-rerun:
    needs: [some-test]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: always() && needs.some-test.result == 'failure'
    steps:
      - name: Retry
        run: | 
          echo "retry"

You can check the behavior here:

Workflow run output
using this workflow file


With if, you can drop the ${{ ... }} brackets.

You mean, without any bracket in the whole expression, right? :) if: always() && needs.some-test.result == 'failure' . I edited the answer. Thanks for the update.

@GuiFalourd thank you for the answer, im in doubt if it makes sense to chanse always() to failure() to make it more explicit, if the needs is always a failure result, than i think there are no other scenarios possible.

I understand the always() function is actually mandatory, otherwise the second job wouldn't trigger when the first job fails.
